# usage of "make"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, verbs

This sentence is from TOEFL, and I want to know the usage (or meaning) of **made** in this sentence.

> After watching this show, my family **made** several lifestyle changes
>   to benefit the environment.

I searched the *[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make)*, and I wonder if the meaning/usage of **made** in this sentence is *perform an action*.

I thought **made** in the sentence has same meaning of **give**. Am I right?

Any answer will help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it means performing some action. And, it's a very general meaning of the verb *make.*

What do you say when you are done with a snowman?

> I *made* a snowman

when done with cookies?

> I *made* cookies for you!

So, when the family made changes, they *brought in* changes in their lifestyles. Simple as that! :)

At times, you don't dive deep into dictionaries! Trust your instinct and try to remember the collocation that you might have read somewhere in dailies or novels. *'make a change'* is a kind of collocation used everywhere.